# Is it possible to use Count( ) function with WHERE Condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, conditional-statements, data-analysis

Consider this table "Cricket"

| **Team 1** | **Team 2** | **Winner** | **Date** | **NewZealandWon** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New Zealand | Pakistan | New Zealand | 2018-01-06 | 1 |
| New Zealand | England | New Zealand | 2018-01-09 | 2 |
| New Zealand | India | India | 2018-01-13 | 1 |
| New Zealand | Bangladesh | New Zealand | 2018-01-16 | 3 |

I am getting above result with the query:

```
SELECT c.[Team 1],c.[Team 2],c.[Winner],
c.[Date], COUNT(*)OVER (Partition by c.[Winner] order by c.[Date]) AS NewZealandWon
FROM Cricket c
Group by c.[Date],c.[Team 1],c.[Team 2],c.[Winner]
Order by c.[Date]
```

But I want to get NULL in the column "NewZelandWon" when winner is not New Zealand
How can I use Where condition or any other condition with Count() function?

The output I want is as follows:

| **Team 1** | **Team 2** | **Winner** | **Date** | **NewZealandWon** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New Zealand | Pakistan | New Zealand | 2018-01-06 | 1 |
| New Zealand | England | New Zealand | 2018-01-09 | 2 |
| New Zealand | India | India | 2018-01-13 | NULL |
| New Zealand | Bangladesh | New Zealand | 2018-01-16 | 3 |

Comment: Not `COUNT(*) OVER` but `COUNT( {definite column or expression} ) OVER`.

Comment: Do you really use MySQL? square brackets are used on SQL Server (MS SQL)...

Comment: "Is it possible to use count" sounds a bit weird - if it wasn't, you would receive a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend `ROW_NUMBER()` over `COUNT(*)`.  Although they are subtly different (different results when there are duplicates in the `ORDER BY`), `ROW_NUMBER()` is more colloquial for what you want to do.

Second, you simply want a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT c.[Team 1], c.[Team 2], c.[Winner], c.[Date],
       (CASE WHEN c.Winner = 'New Zealand'
             THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by c.Winner order by c.[Date])
        END) AS NewZealandWon
FROM Cricket c
ORDER BY c.[Date];
```

I don't think the `GROUP BY` is necessary, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
SELECT c.[Team 1],
       c.[Team 2],
       c.[Winner],
       c.[Date], 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN c.[Team 1] = c.[Winner] THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY c.[Winner]) AS NewZealandWon
FROM Cricket c
Group by c.[Date],c.[Team 1],c.[Team 2],c.[Winner]
Order by c.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join to do that.

```
SELECT c.[Team 1],c.[Team 2],c.[Winner], c.[Date], w.[NewZealandWon]
FROM Cricket c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Date], COUNT(*) AS NewZealandWon FROM Cricket WHERE [Winner]='New Zealand' GROUP BY [Date]) w ON w.[Date]=c.[Date]
```

btw, your question is tagged with "mysql" but the query look like for "mssql" ; perhaps you should correct that ;)

Comment: I got the error:

Column 'Cricket.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Even after adding group by, it is not increasing number of Wins in NewZealandWon Column, so I added "Partition By" function

Modified query which works:

SELECT c.[Team 1],c.[Team 2],c.[Winner], c.[Date], w.[NewZealandWon]
FROM Cricket c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Date], COUNT(*) OVER (Partition by [Winner] order by [Date])AS NewZealandWon FROM Sheet1$ WHERE [Winner]='New Zealand' GROUP by [Date],[Winner]) w ON w.[Date]=c.[Date]

Comment: Oups, sorry, should be 

SELECT c.[Team 1],c.[Team 2],c.[Winner], c.[Date], w.[NewZealandWon]
FROM Cricket c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Date], COUNT(*) AS NewZealandWon FROM Cricket WHERE [Winner]='New Zealand' GROUP BY [Date]) w ON w.[Date]=c.[Date